# save in global variable img attribute location with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I have several sections like this:

```
<section class="one">
    <div class="two  over"  element="myelement1">
          <div class="front" >
            <img src="element.jpg" width ="100%;" height ="100%;" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="back">                        
          </div>
        </div>          
</section>
<section class="one ">
    <div class="two over"  element="myelement2">
          <div class="front" >
            <img src="element2.jpg" width ="100%;" height ="100%;" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="back">                        
          </div>
        </div>          
</section>
```

Then I have a function like:

```
var i = j =0;
$(function () {
    $('.over').hover(function () {
     /*do something*/
    }, function () {
                if ( $(this).attr('element') == 'myelement1'){
            img = $(this).find('img');
            img.attr('src', arr_1[i]);
            i++;
            if(i > arr_1.length-1) i=0;   
        }
                if ( $(this).attr('element') == 'myelement2'){
            img = $(this).find('img');
            img.attr('src', arr_2[j]);
            j++;
            if(j > arr_2.length-1) j=0;   
        } 

     });
})
```

How can I store in global variables or maybe a dictionary 
the values of each `img = $(this).find('img');`  so I do this only once and not every time the user is in `.hover`?

Comment: Where is `.over` in your html code?

Comment: oh sorry I updated the code, It is in `<div class="two  over"  element="myelementN">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you probably don't need to solve the problem you're trying to solve.  Modern computer are so fast that searching the children of an object for imgs is a very fast operation (unless perhaps there are thousands).  So, you probably shouldn't be trying to optimize this at all unless you have actual performance data that says there really is a problem here.

Always measure before optimizing to know what problems are actually there and actually need solving.  Then, measure any potential solution to see if it's actually doing what you need.

As to the actual question you ask, there are a couple options.

You can retrieve it the first time and then just save it in a global:

```
var i = j =0;
var imgs1, imgs2;
$(function () {
    $('.over').hover(function () {
     /*do something*/
    }, function () {
        if ( $(this).attr('element') == 'myelement1'){
            if (!imgs1) {
                imgs1 = $(this).find('img');
            }
            imgs1.attr('src', arr_1[i]);
            i++;
            if(i > arr_1.length-1) i=0;   
        }
        else if ( $(this).attr('element') == 'myelement2'){
            if (!imgs2) {
                imgs2 = $(this).find('img');
            }
            imgs2.attr('src', arr_2[j]);
            j++;
            if(j > arr_2.length-1) j=0;   
        } 

     });
})
```

or, more in the spirit of jQuery, use `.data()` instead of globals:

```
var i = j =0;
$(function () {
    $('.over').hover(function () {
     /*do something*/
    }, function () {
        var imgs = $(this).data("imgList");
        if (imgs) {
            imgs = $(this).find('img');
            $(this).data("imgList", imgs);
        }
        if ( $(this).attr('element') == 'myelement1'){
            imgs.attr('src', arr_1[i]);
            i++;
            if(i > arr_1.length-1) i=0;   
        }
        else if ( $(this).attr('element') == 'myelement2'){
            imgs.attr('src', arr_2[j]);
            j++;
            if(j > arr_2.length-1) j=0;   
        } 

     });
})
```

Comment: but where do I do the `img = $(this).find('img');`, How to asign the value of the resulting search?

Comment: @cMinor - I have two code examples for how to do it.  The first saves the list of images in a global.  The second saves it in a `.data()` reference.  Please ask a more specific question about one of those code examples.

Comment: could you please explain a little the `var imgs = $(this).data("imgList");` on second code?

Comment: @cMinor, I'd suggest you read the [jQuery doc on `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).  The basic idea is that it lets you store javascript data associated with a particular DOM object (and it does it in a safe way that doesn't cause memory leaks like some other ways).  So, we use it as a cache for the list of images for each separate `.hover` object.  If the cache has a value, we use it rather than refinding them.  If not, we get the list of images and then store it away for next time.

Comment: and what would happen if you define `var imgs` ourside function, will that count as global variable?

Comment: @cMinor - that's what my first code example does.  But, you don't have only one list of images so you can't use just one global variable.